# Is an empty string (E or <>) the substring of any/all strings?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, logic

I know that the empty string is a set of no characters, of size 0. Does this mean that it is the substring of any/all strings being that it does not have any characters at all?

And on that notion, if it were to be concatenated to a string A eg. AE ..
would this statement hold true? (AE)^R =(EA)^R

I know the definition of E is that E = (E)^R but I just want to be completely clear on my understanding of the empty string.

Comment: Yes, it is "a" substring of any other string... assuming your definition of substring doesn't assume the string actually has a character.  Assuming R means "reverse" then it is also true since $A=AE=EA$ if $E$ is the empty string.

Comment: @TravisJ So what you are saying is that E is a substring of itself but not a substring of any other string that is of length greater than 0? Thanks for the comment

Comment: It is a substring of itself and, using the definition of substring I'm familiar with, is also a substring of every string.  You'll just want to be careful in case the text you're using defined a substring to be non-empty.

Comment: thanks for the attention to detail this is clear now, post as answer so I can accept!

Comment: <nitpick> Assuming $E$ represents the empty string, $E=E^R$ is a *property* of the empty string, but it certainly isn't a *definition* of the empty string, if for no other reason than the string $\langle\, a\,\rangle$  also satisfies that property. </nitpick>